# What's the best title for Web Application pages?

Tags: forms, web-app, text, title

In a typical Web Application we use the [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) model to manipulate objects in a data store. The user will see a list of the objects on an index page, create a new object on the new page, edit an existing object on the edit page etc. What is the best title to put at the top of the new and edit pages?

I assume the most common title for a new page would be "New {object name}" so if the objects were Posts the title would be "New Post".

Comment: I fear, it is way too generic and with this information, the kind of suggestions you'd get would be too generic too. That would not help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Forget about CRUD

This answer may help explain why CRUD is helpful as a programming pattern but not very helpful as a UX pattern:

- [Form design for CRUD actions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/75203/62445)

Page titles are useful for:

- Informing (or reminding) users about the purpose of the page.
- Providing users with an orientation of where they are in the application/site.
- Providing an [entry point](http://designinginterfaces.com/firstedition/index.php?page=Clear_Entry_Points) to the workflow of the page.

Therefore, a decent way to decide on what page title to use is to look at those design objectives and figure out:

### What would help the user accomplish the page workflow?

- For example, if your CRUD revolves around financial payments it might be: Make a payment,   Adjust payment details,  Revoke a payment.
- If your CRUD app is a restaurant app your titles might be:  Create a reservation, Change a reservation, Cancel a reservation.

...in each of these cases, the language of the title has been crafted to suit a particular business task rather than a technical function (Create, Edit, Delete, etc).

Comment: I think you make some really good points there. While there may not be a better generic answer there might well be better answers for specific situations.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is: test it.

"New {object name}" is a quite standard structure, but it's not necessarily the best option.

As always, the answer depends on many factors (e.g. context, type of user, conventions, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

As a guideline, a good title is what you want visually-impaired people to hear first (via a screenreader) when the page loads.

So yeah - "New post" is good, but for editing a post you'd put something like "editing [post name]".

Essentially, the title should reflect the purpose of the page.